# Manually create dnscache.txt for AWStats

Tags: linux, awstats

According to the docs for AWStats:

> AWStats can do reverse DNS lookups through a static DNS cache file
>   that was previously created manually.

Searching through the docs, as well as a fair bit of Googling, leaves me with one question. How do I manually create the DNS cache file? Is there a Linux command to do this that I've yet to find? This is on a Centos 5.5 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it said underneath, you can use any text editor you want to create a text file with format `ipaddress resolved_hostname`, something like this:

```
192.168.1.11    websrv1
192.168.1.12    websrv2
192.168.1.13    websrv3
```

Don't forget to set `DNSLookup=2`.

---

> I had expected to be able to create the file from existing
>   information, such as the Apache logs.

Sure, you can do it by getting IP address from the Apache's `access_log` and use some tools such as: `dig`, `host`, `resolveip`, ... to resolve to host name, something like this:

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' access_log | sort | uniq | \
while read ip; do \
    if [ `dig +short -x $ip | sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1/' | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then \
        echo -e $ip\\t$(dig +short -x $ip | sed 's/\(.*\)\./\1/') >> dnscache.txt; \
    fi; \
done
```

To continue updating this file, you can run the above command as a cron job and filter only logs in a specific time range (equal to cron interval).

Comment: Looks like I may have misunderstood things a bit. I had expected to be able to create the file from existing information, such as the Apache logs.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the same manual that it says here

> Note: DNS cache file format is 'minsince1970 ipaddress resolved_hostname' 
>   or just 'ipaddress resolved_hostname'

So you could generate it by doing something like:

```
host -t a google.com | awk '{ print $4 " " $1 }' > dnscache.txt
```

or if you have (as is more likely) IPs

```
for ip in 8.8.8.8; do 
    name=`host $ip | cut -d ' ' -f 5`
    if [ X"3(NXDOMAIN)" != X"$name" ]; then
        echo "$ip $name"
    fi
done > dnscache.txt
```

Really though you would want to do something with more error checking and something that works faster than awstats would.